# Desktop application using spotify api - No Callback URI

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, node-webkit

I'm working on a desktop application using spotify API. Given that its a desktop application, what will happen if I do not have a callback URI.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

A typical request looks like this:

```
GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09
```

...allowing their server to take its time doing work and when finished post the results back to your server.  This API expects that you're writing webpages.

That said, if you're trying to create something else--a desktop application--that's "outside of the box" of what they had in mind, then perhaps the easiest way is to write a small webserver that's spun up with your application as part of it.  You'd then bind that to http://127.0.0.1:8888 or similar to the desktop computer.  This webserver would need to respond to the /callback URL of course and then hand over the response to the main thread of your code.

Comment: Do you have an example for this little spin up webserver? Or some more infos?